# Can this SQL CASE WHEN statement be made shorter?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Are there any features within Microsoft SQL Server TSQL that could shorten this `CASE WHEN` statement?

```
   CASE 
         WHEN some_column IS NULL 
         THEN 0
         ELSE 1
   END
```

Comment: Just put it on one line. I know you can use iif as suggested in the answer but I never would personally. I would never reduce readability for sake of shortening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For SQL Server 2012 and later you can use IIF() statement.

```
SELECT IIF(some_column IS NULL , 0 , 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use what [SQL Server documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) calls the "simple" case expression, instead of the "search" case expression that the syntax in the question uses.

```
case some_column when null then 0 else 1 end
```

Not a large difference, but it is shorter.

Comment: I don't think this one works for NULL. Try this: `DECLARE @Null int = NULL; SELECT CASE WHEN @Null IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END; SELECT CASE @Null WHEN NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END`